# Fill data in input field whose parent div has class form in behat

Tags: html, behat

I want to fill data input field whose is the child of the div whose class is `form` in behat

```
<div class="form">
    <form method="post" action="abc" class="redeem-form">
        <span></span>
        <input type="text" value="Voucher Code" id="voucher-code" name="vocuher_code">
    </form>
</div>
```

Feature file is :

```
And I filled in "voucher-code" with "7f2904204489727e" element
```

feature context file :

```
/**
 * @When /^(?:|I )filled in "(?P<field>(?:[^"]|\\")*)" with "(?P<value>(?:[^"]|\\")*)" element$/

 */
public function fillField($field, $values)
{
    $field = $this->fixStepArgument($field);
    $value = $this->fixStepArgument($value);
    $element = $this->getSession()->getPage()->find('xpath','//div[@class="form"]//input[@id="'.$field.'"]');
    $this->getSession()->getPage()->fillField($element, $value);
}
```

Comment: Please, clarify what your problem is, what have you tried and where did you get stuck.

Comment: I want to fill "7f2904204489727e" in input field whose id is "voucher-code" but by selecting it's parent div.

Comment: Do you use Behat 2 or 3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select based on parent then you need to use a css/xpath selector.

Your css would be:

```
div.form #voucher-code
```

Or XPath

```
//div[@class='form']//input[@id='voucher-code']
```

You can remove `fixStepArgument` lines.
Your method should be something like:

```
    /**
     * @When /^I fill "(?P[^"]*)" with "(?P[^"]*)"$/
     */
    public function fillWith($selector, $text)
    {
        $element = $this->getSession()->getPage()->find('css', $selector);
        if($element === null){
            throw new Exception("Element $selector not found");
        }else{
            $element->setValue($text);
        }
    }
```

You should avoid using hard-coded values like `//div[@class="form"]//input` in your step implementation, this will reduce the usability to only elements that are from `div` with the class `form`.